# SUM a column even if some Cells are blank?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to SUM `K` column of Price, but I have some Cells blank, so how I can SUM then even if these cells are blank?

I tried to use this formula `=SUMIFS($K$2:$K,$J$2:$J,"<>",$K$2:$K,"<"&99^99)` but didn't work with me!

Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xoNPfIfrVv7jF8W3Pa67Iu9oJRz2NOncW7oLQ94mWQ4/

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try in cell **L1**:

```
={"TOTAL"; ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(J2:J="",,SUBSTITUTE(K2:K, "$", )*1)))}
```

Comment: Thank you @player0, you helped me a lot today :) , but I tried the same formula with prices in EUR and didn't work `={"TOTAL"; ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(J2:J="",,SUBSTITUTE(M2:M, "€", )*1)))}` how I can fix it and SUM any currency?

Comment: use dots instead of commas when you type numbers with decimals. see your sheet

Comment: Fixed! thank you so much for your time and help bro @player0 <3